# Seo url doens't work with homepage in OpenCart 3

Tags: seo, opencart, opencart-3

I've enabled the option (Use SEO URLs) in settings (Opencart 3). All links such as contact, about, etc are working, except the homepage!

I have added this to the SEO URL page:

- **Query:** common/home
- **Keyword:** home

But it still appears as: `index.php?route=common/home`

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope it will help you as

Please make changes in catalog/controller/startup/seo_url.php

```
if `(($data['route'] == 'product/product' && $key == 'product_id') ||
    (($data['route'] == 'product/manufacturer/info' || 
    $data['route'] == 'product/product') && $key == 'manufacturer_id') || 
    ($data['route'] == 'information/information' && $key == 'information_id')) 
{
```

to

```
if (($data['route'] == 'product/product' && $key == 'product_id') || 
    (($data['route'] == 'product/manufacturer/info' || 
    $data['route'] == 'product/product') && $key == 'manufacturer_id') ||
    ($data['route'] == 'information/information' && $key == 'information_id') || 
    $data['route'] == 'common/home') 
{
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the link on the main logo. You can fix this issue by installing the vQmod that is free to download at this link:
https://www.antropy.co.uk/blog/one-quick-opencart-seo-tip-to-avoid-a-duplicate-home-page/